# Python StructuredProperty to dictionary

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My models all have a method which converts the model to a dictionary:

```
def to_dict(model):
    output = {}
    SIMPLE_TYPES = (int, long, float, bool, dict, basestring, list)
    for key, prop in model._properties.iteritems():
        value = getattr(model, key)

        if value is None:
            continue
        if isinstance(value, SIMPLE_TYPES):
            output[key] = value
        elif isinstance(value, datetime.date):
            dateString = value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
            output[key] = dateString
        elif isinstance(value, ndb.Model):
            output[key] = to_dict(value)
        else:
            raise ValueError('cannot encode ' + repr(prop))
    return output
```

Now, one of my models, `X`, has a `LocalStructuredProperty`:

```
metaData = ndb.LocalStructuredProperty(MetaData, repeated=True)
```

So, repeated=True means this will be a list of MetaData objects. `MetaData` is another model, and it also has the same `to_dict` method.

However, when I call `json.dumps(xInstance.to_dict())`, I get an exception:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + &quot; is not JSON serializable&quot;)
TypeError: MetaData(count=0, date=datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 19, 2, 46, 56, 660000), unique_id=u'8E2C3B07A06547C78AB00DD73B574B8C') is not JSON serializable
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: It's unclear how your definition is an instance method. It's also unclear what you are trying to serialize. If you are trying to serialize the method `X.to_dict` this will certainly fail.

Comment: Almost positive they just forgot the parentheses when posting the question.

Comment: Sorry it should have been xInstance.to_dict() rather than X.to_dict...but that was just a typo on SO, the problem still exists in real life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle this in `to_dict()` and before the level of serializing to JSON, you'll just need a few more cases in your `to_dict()`. Firstly, you said the `to_dict` definition above is a method. I would have it delegate to a function or staticmethod so you have something you can call on `ints` and such without checking the type first. The code will just come out better that way.

```
def coerce(value):
    SIMPLE_TYPES = (int, long, float, bool, basestring)
    if value is None or isinstance(value, SIMPLE_TYPES):
        return value
    elif isinstance(value, datetime.date):
        return value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
    elif hasattr(value, 'to_dict'):    # hooray for duck typing!
        return value.to_dict()
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        return dict((coerce(k), coerce(v)) for (k, v) in value.items())
    elif hasattr(value, '__iter__'):    # iterable, not string
        return map(coerce, value)
    else:
        raise ValueError('cannot encode %r' % value)
```

Then just plug that into your `to_dict` method itself:

```
def to_dict(model):
    output = {}
    for key, prop in model._properties.iteritems():
        value = coerce(getattr(model, key))
        if value is not None:
            output[key] = value
    return output
```

Comment: How does `elif hasattr(value, 'to_dict'):` work? It checks if it has a method named to_dict()?

Comment: Yep. If it's there, call it. It's kind of an "implicit interface" and a lot of stuff in python works that way, but maybe a slightly longer name would have less chance of collisions if it bothers you. Or you could just change it back to the isinstance check.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to serialize is to implement a function

```
def default_encode(obj):
    return obj.to_dict()
```

and then encode your JSON with

```
json.dumps(X.to_dict(), default=default_encode)
```

Comment: Please see my latest comment. I don't know if that makes a difference, but I'm not sure if you're understanding my question. The problem is that when the to_dict() method of the X model encounters a list of MetaData, it doesn't serialize the objects in the list, but rather just puts the list in the dictionary. I want the X instance method to handle the case where the property is a list of MetaData, where in that case make sure to call to_dict() on the MetaData object too..do you get what I'm saying?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve the issue: in the X class, add this to the to_dict() method:

```
            ...         
            if value is None:
                continue
            if key == 'metaData':
                array = list()
                for data in value:
                    array.append(data.to_dict())
                output[key] = array
            elif isinstance(value, SIMPLE_TYPES):
                output[key] = value
            ...
```

Though I'm not really sure how to automate this case where it's not based off key, but rather whenever it encounters a list of custom objects, it first converts each object in the list to_dict() first.